# Creating a arraylist from a class - java

Tags: java, arraylist

I've created a class called Student which will contain information about students.

```
public class Student {
    private int totalPoint;
    private int antalKurser;
    private String program;

// here is constructor and get/set methods
}
```

I'm also trying to create a ArrayList from that class and from what I understand i should write:

```
public class createArrayList {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList new ArrayList<>();
}
```

However Netbeans gives me an error and if I hover the line it says ';' expexted but I'm positive I have written that (above snippet is copy-pasted). When I run the code it says "compiled with errors" but still runs.

Found somewhere else I also could write:

```
ArrayList<Class> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

But then how does the application know which class it should create a list from?

The class Student is in another javafile but is in the same package. What am I missing?

Comment: Where's the `=`? You really need to learn the basic syntax. You can't just copy-paste code without understanding what you're doing.

Comment: `ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();`  you need the =

Comment: In java 8 you don't need to add the class `ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();` If you use java 7 though you need to do `ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();`

Comment: Oh my, that was a silly mistake. Looked through the code thousands of times, still missed it :). Thanks!

Comment: @Axel P. sorry, wrong, Java 6 needed the class in generics creation :-)

Comment: Ah, thanks @AlexP. Seen some places people written that it's not needed to add the second time but no one ever wrote it's different in java 7 and 8.

Comment: @AlexP. actually the diamond operator (<>) was introduced in Java 7, so you can use the short starting from that  version.

Comment: Yep, fingers where faster than brain, indeed java 6 needed the class. Version 7 and above dont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public class createArrayList {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed the = even though I checked the code loads of times.